# Me gustaría saber como podría sacar el porcentaje de cada tipo de pedido por usuario en sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datatables

Esta es una tabla que he tenido que sacar:

| usuario | Pedidos | tipo Pedido |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8 | tipo 1 |
| 1 | 1 | tipo 3 |
| 2 | 2 | tipo 1 |
| 2 | 1 | tipo 2 |
| 3 | 2 | tipo 1 |
| 4 | 2 | tipo 2 |
| 5 | 2 | tipo 2 |

y tendría que sacar los porcentajes, es decir usuario1 si el 70% o mas de sus pedidos es de tipo 1 me devolvería en una columna 'A' y en caso contrario 'B'.

He probado con tablas temporales pero creo que me pisa todos los valores, pone el mismo valor para todos los clientes no a cada uno el suyo.

He probado lo siguiente:

```
WITH T AS (
        SELECT 
            usuario,
            pedidos,
            tipo_pedido
        FROM P
        GROUP BY 
            usuario, 
            tipo_pedido
), T1 AS(
SELECT 
    SUM(pedidos) * 100 AS TOTAL_PROMO
FROM T 
WHERE T.tipo_pedido = 'tipo1'
), T2 AS(
SELECT 
    SUM(pedidos) AS TOTAL_PEDIDOS
FROM T 
)
SELECT 
    DISTINCT T.usuario,
    T1.TOTAL_PROMO/T2.TOTAL_PEDIDOS AS PORCENTAJE,
    CASE 
        WHEN T1.TOTAL_PROMO/T2.TOTAL_PEDIDOS  >= 70 THEN 'A'
        ELSE 'B'
    END AS TIPO
FROM T1,T2,T
ORDER BY PORCENTAJE DESC;
```

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega los detalles de lo que has intentado. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que te estás complicando un poco. Si al final agrupas solo por usuario, no necesitas más que usar una expresión dentro de la función de agregado para limitar las filas que suma. Aquí dejo un ejemplo en el que la primera parte es solo para tener datos de prueba.

```
WITH P(usuario, Pedidos, tipo_Pedido) AS(
    SELECT 1, 8, 'tipo 1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 1, 'tipo 3' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 2, 'tipo 1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 1, 'tipo 2' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 2, 'tipo 1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 2, 'tipo 2' UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 2, 'tipo 2' 
)
SELECT 
    usuario,
    SUM( CASE WHEN tipo_pedido = 'tipo 1' THEN pedidos ELSE 0. END)  / SUM(pedidos) AS Porcentaje,
    CASE WHEN SUM( CASE WHEN tipo_pedido = 'tipo 1' THEN pedidos ELSE 0. END)  / SUM(pedidos) >= 0.7
            THEN 'A'
            ELSE 'B' END AS Tipo
FROM P
GROUP BY usuario;
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias me sirvio mucho! No sabía que podía usar CASE WHEN dentro de un sum. Mucho más facil de esta forma